# bypass Quora captcha in python selenium with 2capthca api

Tags: python, automation, 2captcha

so, i was trying to bypass Quora captcha everything works fine until the token is out and when i send it to the captcha textbox the captcha doesn't get solved or anything
here is the code:

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha
from app import Email_Verfication
import pyautogui as ui
import time

Captcha_solved = False
working = False
web = "https://ar.quora.com/"
driver = Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
def Captcha():
    sitekey = "site_key"
    print(sitekey)

    api_key = "api_key"
    solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
    print("Solving captcha...")
    response = solver.solve_captcha(
        site_key=sitekey,
        page_url=web
    )
    print(response)
    # Send Captcha Key to form
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = '{}';".format(response))
    time.sleep(2)
    ui.moveTo(288, 516)
    ui.leftClick()
    Captcha_solved = True
    return Captcha_solved
```

I tried to find like the captcha submit button or something to click after the token is send to the textbox but i can't find anything.